# How to get a custom webpart from a site using code?

Tags: 2010, web-part, application-pages

I have created a custom webpart.

I want to get that webpart and add it to my custom application page using code. How can I get it?

Comment: What do you mean by get it? Do you want to use it in the application page code?

Comment: Yes, I want to add that custom webpart in my Application page using code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the Web Parts on a specific site by accessing the `Web Part Gallery` List.
For example:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = web.Lists["Web Part Gallery"];
foreach(SPListItem item in list.Items)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanx Moussa,

It worked for me.
So it means all the webparts are stored in a List/Library..
I was struggling for last 5-7 hours to get webpart from site.